# .net 8 wasm changing page wait until page is loaded before really changing

Tags: c#, .net, web, rendering, blazor-webassembly

When I click here:

```
<a href="@Routes.SignIn">Se connecter</a>
```

It does not goes immediately to the "/SignIn" page. It waits until the page is loaded before changing, so stalling on the previous page.

So I set a timer on the onInitilizedAsync in the SignIn page and it is effectivly stalling on the Home page before it changes.

What is going on in .net 8 blazor web assembly?

See here for demo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3IxObz8OvNaQ8iip4B1upxoBCeYZ6U_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok so im gonna take a bilnd shot here, but Blazor WASM load times are VERY dependent on the Users Device. I cant really give you anything definitife on why its SO slow. Things is that the behaivior itself isnt strange, but the time it takes is. Maybe this COULD give you a bit more insight? 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42284

Comment: At the end of the day Blazor WASM uses client side rendering

Comment: What Render mode options did you select in the template?  Where is interactivity set?  What type of page is `SignIn`?  It looks like either the router. the Layout or Signin is doing something before the first render event, but without a view of the code, it's guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

> It waits until the page is loaded before changing, so stalling on the
> previous page.

One reason for this is prerenderding would be enabled by default now in .net 8,you won't be able to click the link during prerendering

Also,make sure you haven't call

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

which would block the thread in lifecycle events;

If you want logical delay without blocking the current thread,you should try with

```
await Task.Delay(3000)
```